# Android Java Regex Replacement Repeated patterns is shown

Tags: java, android, regex

I have got the following bbcodes , say  [369] to be converted to `<img src ...http// />`

But when it comes to replacing multiple items, like

```
 [369] [369] [369] [369]
```

, it turns to be with the following replaced strings 1,2,3,4 tokens , total in 10 respectively.

```
<img src ...http// />   <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />  <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />   <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// /><img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />
```

Input

```
班仔比人陰返轉頭[369] [369] [369] <br/>BTW大家入黎咩都傾下,我地好warm的#yup# #yup# #yup#
```

I would like to implement the string replacement and provide 
Desired Output:

```
班仔比人陰返轉頭<img src ...http// /> <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />  <br/>BTW大家入黎咩都傾下,我地好warm的<img src ...http// /><img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />
```

But when it comes to the execution..
Actual Output:

```
班仔比人陰返轉頭<img src ...http// />       <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />  
    <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />  <br/>BTW大家入黎咩都傾下,我地好warm的<img src ...http// />       <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />  
    <img src ...http// /><img src ...http// /><img src ...http// />
```

Would you please help me check if there is any while loop to cause repeated replacement occurs?

The below is my code:

```
public String replace(String text , String bbcode , String imageLocation ){


            StringBuffer imageBuffer = new StringBuffer (""); 
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(bbcode));
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {


                imageBuffer.append("<img src=\"" + imageLocation + "\" />");
                String replacement = imageBuffer.toString();
                builder.append(text.substring(i, matcher.start()));

                if (replacement == null) {
                    builder.append(matcher.group(0));
                    break;
                } else {
                    builder.append(replacement);
                }

                i = matcher.end();
            }

            builder.append(text.substring(i, text.length()));
            return builder.toString();
        }
```

Comment: what is the exact value of `bbcode` ?

Comment: It will be difficult to answer your question without a working code sample. Please post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: njzkj:   [268] , [459] , any code for converting to images icons for forum

Comment: Duncan : I have provided and taken from the logcat messages

Comment: @RajuGujarati I find your question difficult to understand. But if your code was presented as an SSCCE and you clearly explained your expected output, we could help figure out what is wrong.

Comment: question edited with inputs and output illustrated , Duncan

Comment: @RajuGujarati Ok, that's probably close enough. But seriously, take the time to read the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) website. It makes getting help a *lot* faster and often solves the problem before you post it. Remember that every time you post something that's not an SSCCE, you probably have 30 people around the world trying to turn your code snippet into something executable to play with. Better that *you* undertake that effort on our behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you need to replace all pattern ocurrences with a string, so you can simply do:

```
public String replace(String text , String bbcode , String imageLocation ){
    return text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(bbcode), "<img src=\"" + imageLocation + "\" />");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much . This is a very good example of KISS principle.